# PyQt4 (QTabWidget) how to change position of a Tab Page

Tags: qt, qt4, pyqt4

I am writing an application with PyQt and QT4. I am using a QTabWidget and have set my Tabs to closable and have connected the tabCloseRequsted signal to a method.

```
self.ui.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.onTabClose)

def onTabClose(self,index):       
    self.ui.tabWidget.removeTab(index)
```

This works fine as long as I only close the last Tab Page but if have say 5 Tabs open and close the second Tab the 3rd, 4th and 5th Tab also close. I suppose the way to work around this is to move the tab I want to close to the end so it has the highest index.

One other thing however. Users can create tabs, so when one is closed I don't know if there are one, two or ten tabs open.

How do I move a tab page? or even better is there a better way to close a Tab page?

Comment: OK, I found the problem my self. I had put the self.ui.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.onTabClose) in the same method as that which creates new tabs. This meant that if 5 tabs were created, then when one was closed the tabCloseReqested fired 5 times. By putting this connect statement in the __init__ of my class like I should have done it is only defined once and only fires once when a tab is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I found the problem my self. I had put the self.ui.tabWidget.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.onTabClose) in the same method as that which creates new tabs. This meant that if 5 tabs were created, then when one was closed the tabCloseReqested fired 5 times. By putting this connect statement in the init of my class like I should have done it is only defined once and only fires once when a tab is closed.